# How to update a ListView's row from a download service

Tags: android, listview, android-service, adapter

I hava a `ListView` and when you click on each row it starts downloading from a service in a new `Intent`.

How can I update the `progressBar` in the clicked row from the information that I get from service?

Comment: you can send broadcast from service and receive it in list activity

Answer (score 1):

In service send broadcast like below

```
Intent i = new Intent("Updated_Count");  
i.putExtra("progress", <progress count>); 
i.putExtra("row_index", <row_index>);  
sendBroadcast(i);
```

On other side in activity receive it

```
public class newMessage extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
     {    
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("Updated_Count")){    
        Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
        String progress= extra.getString("progress"); 
        String index = extra.getString("row_index");  
         // now you can play with progress for any particular list row         
     }
}
```

You can place above class as sub class in to your list activity

Don't forget to register/unregister broadcast receiver

Happy Coding!

Comment: if you found it helpful to you and it resolves what you want kindly mark this as answer so that it can be useful to others as well.

Comment: each row of my listview has their own progressBar , so how can I exactly update  the exact row's progressBar ?

Comment: that you have to manage at service end, if there is multiple downloads on going than pass index or id or something unique thing for each row from service via put extra

Comment: when i want to pass the position of the row of listview as the unique id , inside the onclick of the row , it doesnt give me the right position , for example for two rows it returns the same id , like 1 or 0

Comment: that is separate thread, we can't mix up things here otherwise it won't helpful to anyone

Comment: you can search for that or ask as a new question

Comment: You can use URL to distinguish list items.  Details refer to https://github.com/li2/DownloadDemo

Answer (score 0):

Use a broadcast receiver to notify the Progress bar in the activity. In your case the broadcast on receive you will update the progress bar and then notify the adapter of the data change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Broadcast Receiver from service to the activity or fragment.you have to register and unregistered broadcast on `onResume()` and on `onPause()` and created Broadcast instance in activity and sendBroadcast through service you can refer the following example:
http://www.truiton.com/2014/09/android-service-broadcastreceiver-example/